# Access token expires during upload

Tags: box-api

I'm running into a problem with I think is an access token expiring in the middle of an upload. For example, if I currently have a valid (just refreshed) access token, then run:

```
curl -vS --limit-rate 30K 'https://api.box.com/2.0/files/content' -H 'Authorization: Bearer VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN' -F filename=@/tmp/example.zip -F folder_id=12345
```

Which takes more than an hour to upload, I eventually get this in the end:

```
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
...
< WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="Service", error="invalid_token", error_description="The access token provided is invalid."
...
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
```

The files I tested are big, but still within the 250MB upload limit.

Does anyone have any ideas what to do about this problem?

Comment: I don't know whether this is a bug or by design; I'll let the Box folks chime in on that.  But I'm wondering if, in the meantime, you might remove the `limit-rate` cap?

Comment: That will probably work, but it will saturate/kill my Internet connection on big uploads. BTW, it does work great on smaller files.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design.

Currently the only workaround is to enforce (client-side) that your uploads don't take longer than 1 hour from when you fetched your last access token.

This admittedly doesn't accomodate your use case very well. We plan to eventually support chunked uploads, which will help with remedying that problem.